# Remove newlines from string with tr

Tags: bash, tr

I have a file that contains strings with newlines, like this:

```
{"name": "John\n\nMeyer"}
{"name": "Mary\n\nSmith"}
```

How can I remove them using the `tr` tool?

I'm trying this, but the output is bad:

```
$ cat f.json | tr -s '\\n\\n' ' '
{" ame": "Joh Meyer"}
{" ame": "Mary Smith"}
```

With Perl, that same regex works fine:

```
$ cat f.json | perl -pe 's/\\n\\n/ /g'
{"name": "John Meyer"}
{"name": "Mary Smith"}
```

Comment: You can't. `tr` substitutes single characters, not strings.

Comment: Are you sure `\\n` are newlines and not two characters slash \ and `n`?

Answer (score 7):

Try the `-d` option of `tr` to delete characters:

```
tr -d \\n
```

Putting it all together:

```
cat f.json | tr -d \\n
```

You don't want the `-s` option.  The `-s` option of `tr` means "squeeze".  Squeeze removes the specified character if it appears more than once (leaving one).

Alternatively, to avoid using cat and pipe unnecessarily, you can just write the code like this:

```
tr -d \\n <f.json
```

One more note:  If your input really doesn't have newlines but rather has a backslash followed by an 'en', you cannot use `tr` to remove them -- `tr` works on single characters.